# Can't install Elementary OS Odin on a Samsung Book S with NVMe SSD

Tags: install, ssd, secure-boot

I have a Samsung Book S with a NVMe SSD, during installation the drive isn't recognized by Elementary OS Odin, I've already disabled Secure Boot Control e Fast BIOS Mode but nothing change,
any ideas?

Edit: keyboard and touchpad also not working during installation and during the live tryout

Thank you

M.

Comment: Is that a *Galaxy* Book S? If so, then elementary will never work on that machine. The Galaxy Book models use ARM-based CPUs rather than x64.

Comment: Hi, my Galaxy Book S has an i5 CPU, ementary os installer is working, the only problem is it can't see the sdd